# Can we use present perfect tense for "love" or "like"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Ok, "**I like / love him a lot**": we use simple present tense because it expresses a fact and a habit.

can we say "**I have liked / loved him for 2 years**": it expresses an action happened in the past and has been progressing continuously to the present time.

But I seldom hear anyone saying like that.

But it is common to say "**I've been in love with him for 2 years**".

Comment: I agree that it's uncommon, but I can't find any reason why [it's](http://www.oneworldofenglish.com/english_grammar_reference/present_perfect_stative_verbs.htm) wrong.

Comment: It is not uncommon. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22i%27ve%20loved%20you%20since%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Answer (score 3):

> **C**an we say "I have liked / loved him for 2 years": it expresses an action happened in the past and has been progressing continuously to the present time.

Yes, however we tend to say it differently. I suppose it is just not common usage to say, "I've liked him for two years." There is nothing wrong with it, but I would be more likely to see it with an added caveat, ",but then he showed me what a jerk he is." I would say, "We've been good friends for (two) years." "I've been in love with him for years."

Comment: Yes, this is a good point.  The perfect tenses are often used to indicate *relative* action which happened only at or during a certain period of time.  Saying "I have loved her for two years" is grammatically correct, but the *nuance* is that, recently, something changed.  However it is curious that the present perfect of "to love" has a different nuance from "to be in love".